# How to get system specs in .net core on linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, debian

I try to get system informations on linux. My current implementation is working for windows but not totally for linux. In my case i use debian 9.8 minimal with .NET CORE 2.2.
Important informations about: processor, harddisks, memory.
Something that was very creepy, that on linux debian 9 it tells me that the OSPlatform is Windows. I hope that someone can give me some ideas.

I have written a little lib for windows which uses kernel32.dll. The kernel32.dll we cannot use on linux, so i need a another way of implementation for linux to receive the informations (processor, harddisks, memory).

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22660) already open in .Net core GitHub repository.
Hence I believe there is no .Net core API which can help you to achieve this.

There is one workaround I can think of.
You have option to run the bash commands from C# code as shown below ([reference](https://loune.net/2017/06/running-shell-bash-commands-in-net-core/)):

```
public static class ShellHelper
{
    public static string Bash(this string cmd)
    {
        var escapedArgs = cmd.Replace("\"", "\\\"");

        var process = new Process()
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "/bin/bash",
                Arguments = $"-c \"{escapedArgs}\"",
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
            }
        };
        process.Start();
        string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        process.WaitForExit();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then you can run bash command to get output in HTML format ([reference](https://vitux.com/get-linux-system-and-hardware-details-on-the-command-line/)):

```
var output = "sudo lshw -html > hardwareinfo.html".Bash();
```

`lshw` would create an HTML file at specified path.  You have option to somehow parse that information to get the information.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: For memory usage i made a little own wrapper with free -m. Your methods works great. Thank you @Manoj Choudhari